# Retrieving data using ParseQuery

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve information that user have already recorded in my parse.com database into the application. I have researched, and have received assistance, but is still experiencing issues achieving that. In particular, no information is being displayed.

Also, I have also established conditions like setting the limit to 5 people, and where the current user information cannot be retrieved.

Below is the code

```
public class MatchingActivity extends Activity {


protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;   
protected List<ParseUser> mUsers;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.matching);
    // Instantiate a QueryFactory to define the ParseQuery to be used for fetching items in this
     // Adapter.
     ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory =
         new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
           public ParseQuery create() {
             ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = new ParseQuery<ParseUser>("User");
            query.setLimit(5);
             query.orderByDescending("name");
             return query;
           }
         };

     // Pass the factory into the ParseQueryAdapter's constructor.
     ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, factory);
     adapter.setTextKey("name");

     // callback to be fired upon successful loading of a new set of ParseObjects.
     adapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new OnQueryLoadListener<ParseObject>() {
         @Override 
         public void onLoading() {
         // Trigger any "loading" UI
       }



    @Override
    public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> objects, Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
     });

     // Layout reference
     ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSingleClick);
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
    }
```

The XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewSingleClick"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update**
Establishing a relationship between the parsequery and the xml listview

```
public class MatchingActivity extends Activity {


    protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;   
    protected List<ParseUser> mUsers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          Parse.initialize(this, "SBNldSjuNL1F7IOj0OWpwenBWRF7rSkjkm8WFQJj", "DLvq1OqSo87kzEw5j1XNBPKJdXF7dxwRtfEPkxWJ");

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.matching);
        // Instantiate a QueryFactory to define the ParseQuery to be used for fetching items in this
         // Adapter.
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = new ParseQuery<ParseUser>("User");
        query.setLimit(5);
        query.orderByDescending("name");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
          public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // The query was successful.
            } else {
                // Something went wrong.
            }
          }
        });


    }
        }
```

If you require any clarification, kindly advise.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: hello,i have one query.when i have setlimit(100) and my parse database have 2000 record then how to manage all record fetch from this setLimit().please help..i want to get all 2000 record from db.

Answer (score 0):

To query users you need to use the ParseUser.getQuery() method.

https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-querying

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestions. I have adjusted the code, and the result can be found under the update section. I am trying to relate the query to the listview so that the data being retrieved is actually displayed in my actual layout.

Comment: ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = new ParseQuery<ParseUser>("User");
Should be ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

Comment: Thanks for your response; but then I would want to refer to the User class

Comment: Please reread the link and check the querying for users section. It will set up a query for all parse users. You can apply conditions to the query like 'query.whereEqualTo("gender", "female");' and finally you execute the query with the findInBackground method, when it completes you should have a list of ParseUser objects that met the criteria.

Comment: From their documentation, word for word. "To query for users, you need to use the special user query:" this means that by design 
"ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = new ParseQuery<ParseUser>("User");" will not work.

Comment: Thanks. I have briefly navigated through the documentation. Wouldn't I have to link it with my listview somehow in my layout for the information to be displayed?

Comment: Yes, you should look into ListAdapter for that. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html
Here's a tutorial, but you might have better luck googling for your own. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html